# XeTeX + hyperref + glossaries + glossary-superragged = Margin mess

Tags: xetex, margins, glossaries

I am using the `glossaries` package in my dissertation. I am trying to apply the `superragged3col` to my acronym list, which requires an extra package `glossary-superragged`.

The thing is that while using this in XeTeX the acronym list comes out all out place and overlaps the margins.

If I remove the style option it works fine, but I would like to use that style if possible.

[Example](http://goo.gl/fBPwH)
 [Acronym definitions](http://goo.gl/0ttVW)

[image: What happens 1]

[image: What happens 2]

I have narrowed it down to one of two packages. Its either a problem in `hyperref` or `glossary-superragged`. If both are defined the margins are violated.

Comment: Can you provide a *mimmal* example that shows the problem?  (It should be compilable, load just the packages needed to comipile (e.g. just `fontspec` and the relevant glossaries packages) and have just as many acronyms as needed to show the problem.)

Comment: I have uploaded pictures, a sample compiling file (i don't know how to force print the acronyms) and the complete list of acronyms and glossary entries. I am using this in my dissertation report, I don't feel comfortable uploading the whole project.

Comment: That's the point of *constructing* the example.  You shouldn't upload the whole project, and in fact you can create dummy acronyms if you like.  But without something to work with that shows the problem it may be hard to diagnose.

Comment: Added a complete example, the complete preamble and a trash section to add the acronyms. Although I now think that the problem might be unrelated to the `glossaries` packages. Is there an easy way to debug this?

Comment: @Tiago I'm sorry, but this example really is far from minimal.  Part of the debugging process is exactly this: remove all the extra stuff until you can no longer reproduce the problem; then add the last package you removed back in. this will lead you to figure out what packages are actually causing the problem. E.g. remove all your `fancyhdr`, `color`, `listings` stuff, etc.   I notice also, that you mention XeTeX in your question, but aren't using any of the normal XeTeX related packages (`fontspec`) and you're using `babel` instead of `polyglossia`, so why is XeTeX relevant?

Comment: Well I was typesetting the file with it XeTeX. I have recently took interest in it. I was not aware of `polyglossia`. I have mentioned XeTeX because this exact example runs fine under PdfLaTeX.

Comment: @Tiago, ok, so then the source of your problem may be that you are using things in the XeLaTeX version that are incompatible with it, but which work with pdfLaTeX. This is especially true of font selection things (any xelatex document should load `fontspec` for example.)  You should also never use e.g. `inputenc` with xelatex.  So the beginning of the debugging is to reduce the document to the smallest possible document that works in pdflatex and fails with xelatex.  This might help you find out where the problem lies.

Comment: Ok, It is as short as I could make it, I have narrowed it down to either `hyperref` or `glossary-superragged`. Disabling `glossary-superragged` disables the style I am applying. Could it be related to the micro-typography problems XeTeX is said to have?

Comment: Does this example compile in Kile, I cannot get it to work.  Could you post your final glossary?

Comment: My glossary file is on my question, right under the example. It dod compile for me under OS X and latexmk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do not use the style `superragged3col`, because your list of acronyms are too large to fit in three columns. Use instead:

```
\twocolumn
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=superragged,%
               title={List of Acronyms},toctitle={List of Acronyms}]

\onecolumn
\cleardoublepage
```

then you'll get this output:
[image]

Comment: From my understanding the `superragged3col` merely aligns the page numbers, and since those can grow to the sides I don't think your solution will work when I have an acronym in 10 or so pages.

Comment: @Tiago: you maybe right, I didn't read the documentation, looked only for a solution. You do not need the `\twocolumn` macro here, if you didn't like it.

Comment: Well I have decided to change the style. Not to this one but It will do.